# image map software for coordinates using magic wand

Tags: html, mapping, coordinates

Quick question... there are lots of ways to create an image map (old school, I know!) for a web page, but I have a requirement for one. I want to have an interactive map showing UK counties. I have the map, I have "mapspinner" (also dreamweaver) to do the polymap...

but, I was wondering if there was a way to use a magic wand to get the area's coordinates?

I have tried using photoshop export to illustrator paths, but the file doesn't contain any coords (as expected really!).

Does anyone know a way to do this? (I see that fireworks might do it, but I don't have that software)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP can do this. See http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-imagemap.html for a tutorial of exactly the task you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this, so I wrote an addon for Photoshop to export all coordinates of a path.

You can find it here: https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/2389

The way to use this with magic wand would be:

- create marquee using wand
- right click -> Make Work Path..
- (rename your path)
- (repeat)
- (install pathToCoords), go Window -> Extensions -> pathToCoords
- click Export

Hope this is useful to someone.